# Cannot remove two vowels in a row

Tags: python

I have to enter a string, remove all spaces and print the string without vowels. I also have to print a string of all the removed vowels.

I have gotten very close to this goal, but for some reason when I try to remove all the vowels it will not remove two vowels in a row. Why is this? Please give answers for this specific block of code, as solutions have helped me solve the challenge but not my specific problem

```
# first define our function
def disemvowel(words):
    # separate the sentence into separate letters in a list
    no_v = list(words.lower().replace(" ", ""))
    print no_v
    # create an empty list for all vowels
    v = []
    # assign the number 0 to a
    a = 0

    for l in no_v:
        # if a letter in the list is a vowel:
        if l == "a" or l == "e" or l == "i" or l == "o" or l == "u":
            # add it to the vowel list
            v.append(l)
            #print v
            # delete it from the original list with a
            del no_v[a]
            print no_v
        # increment a by 1, in order to keep a's position in the list moving
        else:
            a += 1

    # print both lists with all spaces removed, joined together
    print "".join(no_v)
    print "".join(v)

disemvowel(raw_input(""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mistakes

So there are a lot of other, and perhaps better approaches to solve this problem. But as you mentioned I just discuss your failures or what you can do better.

**1. Make a list of input word**

There are a lot of thins you could do better

```
no_v = list(words.lower().replace(" ", ""))
```

You don't replaces all spaces cause of `"  " -> " "` so just use this instead

```
no_v = list(words.lower().translate( None, string.whitespace))
```

**2. Replace for loop with while loop**

Because if you delete an element of the list the `for l in no_v:` will go to the next position. But because of the deletion you need the same position, to remove all the vowels in no_v and put them in v.

```
    while a < len(no_v):
      l = no_v[a]
```

**3. Return the values**

Cause it's a function don't print the values just return them. In this case replace the `print no_v` `print v` and just return and print them.

```
return (no_v,v) # returning both lists as tuple
```

**4. Not a mistake but be prepared for python 3.x**

Just try to use always `print("Have a nice day")` instead of `print "Have a nice day"`

## Your Algorithm without the mistakes

Your algorithm now looks like this

```
import string
def disemvowel(words):
    no_v = list(words.lower().translate( None, string.whitespace))
    v = []
    a = 0
    while a < len(no_v):
        l = no_v[a]
        if l == "a" or l == "e" or l == "i" or l == "o" or l == "u":
            v.append(l)
            del no_v[a]
        else:
            a += 1
    return ("".join(no_v),"".join(v))

print(disemvowel("Stackoverflow is cool  !"))
```

**Output**

For the sentence `Stackoverflow is cool  !\n` it outputs

```
('stckvrflwscl!', 'aoeoioo')
```

## How I would do this in python

Not asked but I give you a solution I would probably use. Cause it has something to do with string replacement, or matching I would just use regex.

```
def myDisemvowel(words):
    words = words.lower().translate( None, string.whitespace)
    nv = re.sub("[aeiou]*","", words)
    v = re.sub("[^a^e^i^o^u]*","", words)
    return (nv, v)

print(myDisemvowel("Stackoverflow is cool  !\n"))
```

I use just a regular expression and for the nv string I just replace all voewls with and empty string. For the vowel string I just replace the group of all non vowels with an empty string. If you write this compact, you could solve this with 2 lines of code (Just returning the replacement)

**Output**

For the sentence `Stackoverflow is cool  !\n` it outputs

```
('stckvrflwscl!', 'aoeoioo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying `no_v` while iterating through it. It'd be a lot simpler just to make two new lists, one with vowels and one without.

Another option is to convert it to a while loop:

```
while a < len(no_v):
    l = no_v[a]
```

This way you have just a single variable tracking your place in `no_v` instead of the two you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

For educational purposes, this all can be made significantly less cumbersome.

```
def devowel(input_str, vowels="aeiou"):
  filtered_chars = [char for char in input_str 
                    if char.lower() not in vowels and not char.isspace()]
  return ''.join(filtered_chars)

assert devowel('big BOOM') == 'bgBM'
```

To help you learn, do the following:

- Define a function that returns `True` if a particular character has to be removed.
- Using that function, loop through the characters of the input string and only leave eligible characters.
- In the above, avoid using indexes and `len()`, instead iterate over characters, as in `for char in input_str:`.
- Learn about list comprehensions.
- (Bonus points:) Read about the `filter` function.